# Let $(s_n)$ be a sequence with $s_1, s_2, ..., s_{100}$ being positive and $s_n < 0 $ for all $n > 100.$ Assume $\lim s_n = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

Let $(s_n)$ be a sequence with $s_1, s_2, ..., s_{100}$ being positive and $s_n < 0 $ for all $n > 100.$ Assume $\lim s_n = 0$

What is $\lim \frac{1}{s_n} $?

My thought:
Since $\lim s_n = 0$,
$\forall \epsilon > 0,$ there exists $N$ such that $\forall n > N,$   $\mid s_n - 0 \mid <\epsilon$
Then $\mid s_n \mid < 0$
$-\epsilon < s_n < \epsilon$
$-\epsilon < s_n$ (only care about lower bound)
$\frac{-\epsilon}{s_n} > 1$ (because $n$ should be large enough for $s_n$ to converge to $0$?? Then $s_n$ is negative.. question point)
$\frac{1}{s_n} < - \frac{1}{\epsilon}$
Therefore $\frac{1}{s_n}$ converges to $-\infty$.

I was wondering if that question point step works.. and also other steps.

Comment: Yes, it works. To make it a bit more precise you could write that we can assume that $N\geq100$. In that case $s_n<0$ and therefore $-\epsilon<s_n$ implies $-\frac{\epsilon}{s_n}>1$

Comment: @leoli1 so even I started with "$\forall \epsilon$", I can choose N large enough because even when I choose $\epsilon$ to be really large, I can just pick any large N so that $s_n$ are close to 0? not to mention when $\epsilon$ is really small.

Comment: If you know that all $n>N$ satisfy some property then certainly also all $n$ with $n>100$ *and* $n>N$ satisfy that property, so if $N<100$ we can just replace $N$ with $100$ and the statement is still true.

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote is fine until (and including) $-\varepsilon<s_n<\varepsilon$.

At this point, you should use the fact that $n>100\implies s_n<0$ to deduce that, if $N$ is large enough, then $-\varepsilon<s_n<0$, which implies that $0<-s_n<\varepsilon$ and that therefore $-\frac1{s_n}>\frac1\varepsilon$, which is equivalent to $\frac1{s_n}<-\frac1\varepsilon$.

So, it is indeed true that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{s_n}=-\infty$: for any $M<0$, you know that $$\frac1{s_n}<\frac1{-1/M}$$if $n$ is large enough, and this is the same thing as asserting that $\frac1{s_n}<M$.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't quite complete the last part of the proof, although you were close. And I also cleaned up what you have done.

Let's start with the following:

Lemma: Given $\ r<0,\ $ there exists $\ \varepsilon>0\ $ such that $-\frac{1}{\varepsilon} = r.\ $ **Proof**: Let $\ \varepsilon = \frac{-1}{r}.$

Now, let's begin the main proof. Let $\ \varepsilon>0.$

Since $\lim s_n = 0\quad $ and $\quad s_n < 0\quad \forall\ n \geq 101,\ $ there exists $\ N\geq 101\ $ such that $\ -\epsilon < s_n < 0\quad \forall\ n \geq N.$

$s_n<0\ $ and $\varepsilon>0 \implies \frac{-1}{\varepsilon s_n} > 0,\ $ so multiplying both sides of $-\varepsilon < s_n\ $ by $\ \frac{-1}{\varepsilon s_n}\ $ gives:

$\frac{1}{s_n} < - \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \quad \forall\ n \geq N \geq 101\quad.$

$\varepsilon>0\ $ is arbitrary in all of this, so using the Lemma, given any negative number $r<0,\ $ we can choose $\varepsilon>0\ $ so that $\frac{1}{s_n} < r = - \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \quad \forall\ n \geq N \geq 101.$

This matches a definition of $\frac{1}{s_n}$ **diverges** to $-\infty$.